# C# Copy to disk a group of file from Resources

Tags: c#, installation

I'm doing a installer program and I want to install a bunch of file to the disk. I don't know if that's the best way, but I added my files to MyProject's Resources in subfolders (Effect, Images etc.). I would like to be able to copy to the disk each files to the right folder.

What I'm doing:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test\\Effects\\rfx_engColdStart.fx", Resources.rfx_engColdStart);
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test\\Effects\\rfx_engCold2.fx", Resources.rfx_engCold2);
```

I want to copy the whole folder called Effects from my Resources to disk or if that's not possible simply find all .fx file and copy them to disk. I have to do this with differents files that goes in different locations.

How can I achieve that? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you writing your own installer instead of using something similar to wix?  http://wixtoolset.org/

Comment: I want to build my own installer because I have to link the installer to my server database, custom login / activation system. Everything is done but I simply need to find a way to extract allot of file like a unzip.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what your searching for?

```
//For all the files in a certain folder, then just replicate it for every different folder. Btw, if you made the application, you should not want it to search for the files and then copy it, its vulnerable to a corrupted input attack when you do this.
for (int i =0; i < filesInFolder+1; i++)
{
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test\\Effects\\rfx_engCold"+i.ToString()+".fx",Ressources.rfx_engCold[i]);
}
```